# Windows Networking: Prompt For Unique Credentials, On Multiple Network Shares, Without Mapping

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

I have several folders shared on a Windows 10 PC.  Each has a different user name and password.

I would like to have the clients prompted for credentials when they attempt to open the share in the network explorer.

I found that disabling the guest account on the host will prompt for a username and password, but once any valid credentials are entered only the share folder associated with those credentials is accessible.

Afterward, none of the other shares prompt for a credentials.  Instead they simply say "You do not have permissions... "

I know I can map each of the folders with unique credential.  However, I would like to avoid mapping the drives as users accessing these shares will only do so briefly and then never access them again.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep this setup and require different credentials is silly.

Each user needs one username and password combination, that's it. Leave the rest to groups.

1. Organize on paper which users need access to what.
2. Create groups for the users to be in, with other users needing the same access.
3. Allow the groups access to the shares they require, in the Sharing tab and the Security tab .
4. Test the permissions on each folder.
5. Tweak as needed.

Adding a user requires adding them once, then putting them in a group for what they can access. Users can be in multiple groups.

Comment: Okay this makes sense.  Just from an academic standpoint there is no way to accomplish this the "silly" way right?  

If I wanted to hand out the credentials to various users and have they gain access to different groups through out the day (for say wins at a LAN party, they gain access to new details in a different share) they would need to sign out and re-sign in and couldn't just keep entering different credentials to gain access to different groups?

Comment: Right. That's how connecting to a server works